# How do I combined a line graph and a bar graph in R with two different y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have my code with that created two different graphs. I want to combine the graphs into one graph with "Elevation on the primary y axis and "Precipitation" on the secondary y axis. Is this possible or would it be best to stick with having the two graphs on top of each other?

```r
pe1.plot <- combine.df %>% filter(site== "VWP 1") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = datetime, y = elevation)) +
  geom_line(color = "blue")+
theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(vjust = 1), 
        plot.caption = element_text(vjust = 1), 
        plot.background = element_rect(linetype = "solid")) +labs(title = "VWP 1", x = "Date", y = "Elevation (MSL)")

precip.plot <- ggplot(precip.df, aes(x = datetime, y = precipitation)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")+
  theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(vjust = 1), 
        plot.caption = element_text(vjust = 1), 
        plot.background = element_rect(linetype = "solid")) +labs(x = "Date", y = "Pecipitation (in.)")

pe1.plot+precip.plot + plot_layout(ncol = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Look into `sec.axis` argument (to `scale_*_continuous`) and the `ggplot2::sec_axis` function needed to use it. You might have trouble if your x axis is not continuous in both, currently I believe `sec.axis` is continuous-only.

Comment: It is possible. It would be easier for  us to test our suggested answer with a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0):

Possible but kind of a pain:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(42)
my_data = tibble(date = seq.Date(as.Date("2020-01-01"), 
                                 as.Date("2020-06-30"), by = "day"),
                 line_y = seq(698, 700, length.out = 182) + rnorm(182, sd = 0.1),
                 bar_y = rpois(182, c(0,0,5))/10)


ggplot(my_data, aes(date)) +
  geom_line(aes(y = line_y)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = (2*bar_y) + 695)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(695, 699.5, by = 0.5), 
                     labels = c(rep("", 6), seq(698, 699.5, by = 0.5)),
                     
                     sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. - 695) / 2, 
                                         breaks = seq(0, 1, by = 0.25))) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(695, NA), expand = 0)
```

[image]